# Does npm shrinkwrapping a module in npm do anything?

Tags: node.js, npm

If I shrinkwrap a module I publish to npm, does that affect in any way the installation of modules that depend on that module? Or does npm simply ignore the shrinkwrap file of dependencies and only look at the package.json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NPM will not ignore the shrinkwrap since it was made for this specific purpose. Instead, NPM will ignore package.json whenever it encounters a shrinkwrap. You essentially use shrinkwrap to *lock down* the currently installed versions of your dependencies, even if you haven't stated any specific versions in your package.json.

As stated in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-shrinkwrap.html):

> This command locks down the versions of a package's dependencies so that you can control exactly which versions of each dependency will be used when your package is installed. The "package.json" file is still required if you want to use "npm install".